# Select highest level td's in nested table structure with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select the highest level of `td`s in a nested table structure like this (inside the first level `td`s there are more tables with more `td`s that shouldn't be selected

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>        <!-- this is what I want to select -->
      <table /> <!-- more td's inside that I don't want to select -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>        <!-- this is what I want to select -->
      <table /> <!-- more td's inside that I don't want to select -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To select the desired `td`s would be easy: `table > tr > td`. However there might be `table`s with `tbody` tags:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>        <!-- this is what I want to select -->
        <table /> <!-- more td's inside that I don't want to select -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>        <!-- this is what I want to select -->
        <table /> <!-- more td's inside that I don't want to select -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

That itself would be easy as well: `table > tbody > tr > td`.

How can I find an easy expression that doesn't rely on the `>` child selector and works universally?

Something like `table tr > td` (which obviously wouldn't work since it selects `td`s inside the nested table. Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to find something unique about the wrapping table to target it, like it's parent element, an ID, the index etc.

Comment: `table > tbody > tr > td` will work universally and would also probably be the fastest solution. Why are you against it?

Comment: most browsers will assume you forgot to add `tbody` and will add it themselves (with some exceptions because of doctype). Also I know this sounds dull but if you only have two posibilities wouldn't  a selector like `$('table > tbody > tr > td', 'table > tr > td');` do the trick? Without that it will require alot of parent proofing to get the right `td`

Comment: @Spokey of course it would work but I am eager to learn - so I thought there might be a better way to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expressed in my comment, I'm all in favor of `table > tbody > tr > td`, but as an alternative, you can use

```
td:not(td td)
```

This selects all `td` elements that are not descendants of a `td` element. But note that this will **only** work with jQuery, because you usually cannot use complex selectors with `:not`.

Alternatively, use the `.not` method:

```
$('td').not('td td')
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
$('#tbl1').find('tr:first').parent().children().not(':not(td)')
```

**.not(':not(td)')** removes not **td** tags.

Examples:

```
<table id="tbl1">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="something"> 
  <td>2</td>
  <td> 
       <table>
          <tr><td>1</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="something"> 
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="tbl2">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="something"> 
  <td>2</td>
  <td> 
       <table>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="something"> 
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Code:

```
var r1 = $('#tbl1').find('tr:first').children();
var r2 = $('#tbl1').find('tr:first').children().not(':not(td)');
var r3 = $('#tbl2').find('tr:first').children();
var r4 = $('#tbl2').find('tr:first').children().not(':not(td)');

console.log ("r1: ", r1.length);
console.log ("r2: ", r2.length);
console.log ("r3: ", r3.length);
console.log ("r4: ", r4.length);
```

Output:

```
"r1: ", 4
"r2: ", 3
"r3: ", 4
"r4: ", 3
```